# how to resolve these error, UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl-chk and no j3dcore-d3d in java.library.path

Tags: java, native, sweethome3d

how to resolve these error, UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl-chk and no j3dcore-d3d in java.library.path

SEVERE: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl-chk in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-d3d in java.library.path.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception tell you that needed native libraries are not in the library search path.

Following native libraries are for example expected on a Windows system

```
j3dcore-d3d.dll
j3dcore-ogl-cg.dll
j3dcore-ogl-chk.dll
j3dcore-ogl.dll
```

They need to be either in a directory specified by the PATH environment variable or in a directory specified with the JVM option `-Djava.library.path=...`